# Give the partition of C * C associated with S

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$C = \{i, -1, -i, 1\}$, where $i^2 = -1$.
The relation $S$ on $C \times C$ given by $(x,y)S(u,v)$ iff $xy = uv$ is an equivalence relation. Give the partition of $C \times C$ associated with $S$.

Sorry, I wasn't quite sure how to deal with this problem, could someone help me out?

Comment: What, in the question, are you not sure about?

Answer (score 0):

The partition of $C \times C$ induced by $S$ is given as follows:
$$C \times C = S_1\sqcup S_{-1}\sqcup S_{i}\sqcup S_{-i} $$
where $S_j$ denotes the subset $\{ (x, y) \in C \times C : xy=j\}$ for $j \in C$. We can write down all the elements.

$$S_1=\{(1,1),~(-1,-1),~(i,-i),~(-i,i) \}$$ $$S_{-1}=\{(1, -1), ~(-1, 1), ~(i, i), ~(-i, -i) \} $$ $$ S_i = \{(1, i), ~(-1, -i), ~(i, 1), ~(-i, -1) \}$$ $$S_{-i} =\{(1, -i), ~(-1, i), ~(i, -1), ~(-i, 1) \} $$